# Margin: 0 auto is not centering my image

Tags: html, css, center

I'm very new to all of this and am trying to build this website, but the main image on the page is not centering. I've tried all sorts of centering things but they don't work. Also, the width percentage is ignored too.

I've readjusted margin/padding to 0. don't know what it could be.

css for the picture:

```
#pictures img{
    width:"70%";
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-top: 20px;
```

}

and the html div that has to do with it:

```
<div id="pictures">
    <img src="img/homepage.png" alt="HomePage"></div>
```

FULL HTML

```
<!DOCTTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Jacobs Bookeeping</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-no-grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

</head>


<body>

    <div class="container clearfix">

    <div id="main">

    <div id="header">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Jacobs Bookkeeping Logo" width="248">
        </div>


    <div id="twitter">
        <a href="twitter.com/"><img src="img/twitter.jpg" alt="Twitter"></a>
    </div>

    <div id="facebook">
        <a href="www.facebook.com/"><img src="img/facebook.jpg" alt="Facebook"></a>
    </div>


        <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
        </ul>


        <div id="pictures">
                    <img src="img/homepage.png" alt="HomePage">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="copyright">
                <p>K. RONI JACOBS, <em>KEEPER OF THE BOOKS</em> — <a href="jacobsbookkeeping1@gmail.com">EMAIL JACOBS BOOKKEEPING </a> — CALL 206.861.5664 — &copy; 2013 JACOBS BOOKEEPING &nbsp &nbsp</p>

            </div>

</body>



</html>
```

FULL CSS

```
html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

 }

 body {

    font-family:'Futura', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 13;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#main {
    border-top: 10px solid #EAE1C9;
    border-right: 10px solid #EAE1C9;
    border-left: 10px solid #EAE1C9;    
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background: url('../img/bg-jacobs.jpg') repeat;
    background-color:#96B9BF;
}


a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#facebook img{
    float: right;
    padding: 45px 5px 10px 10px;
    position: static;
}

#twitter img{
    float: right;
    padding: 45px 50px 20px 0px;
    position: static;
}
#header img {
        padding: 40px 0px 0px 40px;
        float: left;
        position: static;
}

ul.nav {
    margin-top: 45px;
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: right;
    position: relative;

}

ul.nav li {
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 60px;
    display: inline;

}

ul.nav li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#pictures img{
    width:"80%";
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;

}

#copyright {
    text-align: right;
    background: #867131;
    border-top: 10px solid #EAE1C9;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: white;
}


.container{
    width: auto; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}



.clear{clear:both;display:block;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0}.clearfix:after{clear:both;content:' ';display:block;font-size:0;line-height:0;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0}* html .clearfix,*:first-child+html .clearfix{zoom:1}
```

Comment: oh boy that did not format well

Answer (score 21):

Put `display: block;` on it. By default, images are inline.

Comment: +1 - But what about being inline prevents it from having margin?

Comment: Actually inline elements can have left and right margin, it's just that `auto` doesn't work on them. If I'm not mistaken, this is because they can have no predefined width, so `auto` can't be calculated

Comment: It moved it over from the left side to a bit more to the right, but it's not centered all the way. close though!

Comment: Well, the problem is that you didn't clear your navigation, which is right floated. Since your already have a "clearfix" there, the fix is to wrap the "nav" list into a DIV that has the `clearfix` class. [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/cd8En/). This should also fix other issues you will likely have with your layout. Also, `width: "80px"` has no effect. Value must not have quotes around it. @pzin's answer should also work

Answer (score 3):

To center `inline` —default for image— or `inline-block` elements, just **center it as text**. This means, you will need to use `text-algin` on the parent element:

```
div#pictures {
  text-align: center;
}
```

The other solution is the one from @One Trick Pony, and display the image as a `block` element and just then apply the automatic margin.

Comment: no luck. maybe it's something int the rest of my code that i don't understand yet...

Comment: This isn't about luck...
You need to **remove quotes from width value** in the `div#picture img` rule. Also, the `text-algin: center` must be specified on the **PARENT**, not on the image. And use just one solution, the one where image stays as an inline element and center the parent element, or just apply automatic margins plus display image as a block element. Don't mix things.

Answer (score 3):

```
#pictures img{
display:block;
}
```

**Add this code then i will be centered**

Answer (score 2):

i know this is an old post, but wanted to share how i solved the same problem.

My image was inheriting a float:left from a parent class. By setting float:none I was able to make margin:0 auto and display: block work properly. Hope it may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Remove img from #pictures and then put the image inside that div.
2. Add the #pictures to the image Tag in html (inline style).

You might remove the display tag in #pictures.

Good luck with that.