# Can't center an image with margin: 0 auto

Tags: html, css

I've been learning HTML and CSS for the past month,
I have built some webpages but for some reason this one is somehow problematic.

I can't seem to center an image with `margin:0 auto`, although the image responds well to specified margin values .
The image is classified "fotosize", inside a div called "italy", inside a header tag.

**EDIT:** thanks for the solution, but there is a similar deal with two other pictures that this solution does not apply.
http://jsfiddle.net/1Ldf8j79/

thanks.

Comment: I think you must set `display` to `block` for the image.

Comment: also this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502541/margin-0-auto-is-not-centering-my-image

Comment: I have managed to do what you wrote with "display: block", but there is another picture at the top which I cant seem to center - all the parent elements have % width and height, changed the display in all of them , and tried to text-allign - no success. [http://jsfiddle.net/1Ldf8j79/]

Answer (score 3):

Because by default, image elements are [inline (replaced) elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width), they don't behave the same way as block elements as far as the `margin: 0 auto` rule goes.

You can make it work though, simply by changing the `display` CSS property for your image:

```
.fotosize {
    width:100px;
    height:72px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px outset gold;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ssfkgsLp/1/)

---

If you aren't able to change the display of your image, then you will have to centrally align the inline content of `#italy` using `text-align`:

```
#italy {
    border-radius: 500px;
    width: 33%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FE1800 10%, #FFFFFF 66%, #40C401 100%, transparent 100%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ssfkgsLp/2/)

Comment: In fact `img` element is an inline replaced element http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width. sorry for my last comment that was wrong.